# Java Multi-threading -- Why do we need to look into main memory(RAM) if we have shared heap?

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, shared-memory, heap-memory

If we apply volatile keyword, threads read from main memory instead of its own cache. If we have common heap memory then why do we need to look into main memory? Do we wanna say main memory(RAM) and heap are same?

Comment: Each thread has a copy of heap data for performance reasons. Using volatile force it look into heap, in case other thread modified this object which is shared among many threads. This is very broad question, could you provide some example you need help with?

Comment: The JVM's heap resides in main memory.

Comment: FWIW: There is no "main memory" or "cache" in the Java Language. Those things are implementation details. The Java Language Specification only speaks of object fields and static variables and the rules that govern when (if ever) an update to one of those by one thread will become visible to some other thread.

Comment: Using volatile doesn't force to read from main memory. In theory using volatiles CPUs could read from the cache indefinitely; the caches are the source of truth.. they will never be out of sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two aspects to this question.

**heap/RAM/main memory**

In this context, the terms RAM and main memory refer to the same thing. I will say RAM in the rest of this post. These terms make sense on hardware level and software level.
Heap is a term used on software level only to denote a RAM area in which objects can be created.

On software level, besides the heap, there is the stack. The stack is also a memory area in the RAM. In java, the stack can only contain primitive data types like int or long, and pointers (memory addresses) to objects, which are inside of the heap.

**volatile**

On hardware level, invisible to the programmer, there are a number of memory caches for caching frequently reused data. This makes the computer run faster, because memory accesses take less time. In almost all cases, you as a programmer will not see these caches anywhere. You can only notice performance gains in certain special cases.
When multiple CPU cores (think of threads) access the same memory address in the RAM, the data they access might actually come from a cache in between the RAM and the CPU. If a variable is **not** flagged as volatile, then these caches can contain different data, and thus different CPU cores will receive different data for the same memory address. This is, very often, undesired. Therefor the volatile keyword exists. If you flag a variable as volatile, the CPU cores make sure they read directly from the RAM and update memory writes back to the RAM to make sure other CPU cores can access the up to date value.

Comment: Using volatile doesn't force reading from main memory. This is a misconception.

On the X86 caches are always coherent. So it can't happen that you read stale data from a cache. It could be that the memory isn't in sync with the cache.. that is fine.. The cache is the source of truth.. main memory isn't.

Comment: @pveentjer this sounds very interesting. Can you elaborate on this, please, and maybe post links?

Comment: If you want to go in-depth: https://www.morganclaypool.com/doi/abs/10.2200/S00962ED2V01Y201910CAC049

Comment: @pveentjer this is a 300p book. I'm sure there is a specific part in the book that you had in mind when posting the link, right?

Comment: The first few chapters give you most of the basics including a relatively short introduction chapter about cache coherence that might answer your questions.

Comment: Yes, I did. I didn't go through the whole book, but I spend quite some time in the first few chapters.

Answer (score 0):

> If we have common heap memory then why do we need to look into main memory?

The Java heap is stored in the computer's main memory.

Other things stored in the main memory are thread stacks, the method area, and the constant pool. These are presented in the JVM specification section 2.5 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5

Answer (score 0):

`If we apply volatile keyword, threads read from main memory instead of its own cache.`

This is not correct.  The volatile variable makes sure there is a happens before edge between a write of that variable and any subsequent read of that variable. And this causes the access to be sequentially consistent. If you would have 2 conflicting accesses (2 threads accessing the same address and at least one of them is a write) and these conflicting accesses are not ordered by a happens before edge, then you have a data race and with data races program behavior is undefined.

You should not think in terms of main memory and caches; think in terms of the Java Memory Model and in this case of the volatile variable rule. Caches are always coherent on the X86; so it is not possible to read stale data from a cache.

FYI: RAM is shared memory between all the CPUs. Heap is a usage of RAM, just like stacks. In Java objects are typically created on the heap (I don't know of any stack based allocation JVM implementations; only scalar replacement).